# Error: basic string:_M_replace_aux

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

This is an error from the past however renaming the wallet fails with error: no keyfile found. if i rename both I get error:_M_replace_aux.

Am I doing it wrong?  What cache files are people referring to?

Ubuntu OS throughout the wallets life.

Thank you!!!!! (in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I was renaming the wallet and then trying to load new wallet name to gen. key.

Totally assbackards from what people said. Sorry.